# Object reference not set to an instance of an object test if a button in other Form is cliked

Tags: c#, winforms, button, reference

I have 2 Forms,FormA and FormB,for FormA have a button,in FormB I have to test if this button in formB is cliked,I tried this code:

FormA://in which I have the button

```
public bool button6WasClicked = false;

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ............   
  button6WasClicked = true;
}
```

FormB://in which I have to test if the button in FormA is cliked

```
FormA nv;

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (nv.button6WasClicked) //the error is at this line
    { 
        ..........
        button6WasClicked = false;
    }
}
```

I have this problem :
[image]

the Translation is:Object reference not set to an instance of an object

thanks for Help :)

Comment: Are you opening `FormA` from `FormB` ?

Comment: Pass `FormA` instance to `FormB` constructor and access fields, if `FormB` is opened by `FormA`

Comment: @Lina When you open `FormB` pass a reference of `FormA` to it ? (perhaps through the constructor)

Comment: I guess it should not be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess below code should work :-

in constrctor you have to pass your `FormA`  object as shown below :-

```
public FormA nv;

    Public FormB(FormA formA)
    {
        nv = formA;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (nv.button6WasClicked)
        { 
            ..........
            nv.button6WasClicked = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "button6" is on a different form, it looks like op has two fields with the same name, your edit still won't ever make `button6WasClicked` to be true

Comment: I guess he has Boolean in FormA only @Sayse

Comment: And creating a second `formA` isn't going to help that

Comment: I have made some update can it work now @Sayse?

Comment: thanks guys it works for FormB,but now if I try to add a new FormC in which I have to test if the button in Forma is cliked I got the same error

Comment: whatever you have done for FormB can be done for FormC also @Lina

Comment: yes @Neel I did the same thing for C,and I think I have a problem with the "if statement" thanks for Help to this problem,I will try to solve it :)